# Monus operator macro

Tags: math-operators

I'm doing some CS theory papers and need to use a monus operator.

Picture below:

[image]

What package should I use to be able to use it? I've Google'd, but nothing came up.

Thanks for the help.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to look up a symbol or identify a math alphabet?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/14/how-to-look-up-a-symbol-or-identify-a-math-alphabet)

Comment: @Werner Any idea why [Detexify2](http://detexify.kirelabs.org/classify.html) fails to solve this? Even after repeated tries?

Comment: @MMA: I tried as well, but the symbol is available in the [Comprehensive LaTeX Symbol List](http://ctan.org/pkg/comprehensive) (and therefore a duplicate). It may be a very low sought-after symbol, and [Detexify](http://detexify.kirelabs.org/classify.html) can be trained to recognize symbols once it's found. Minimal training -> low recognition, perhaps.

Comment: @Werner I also had to look up CLST when Detexify2 failed. Just wondering why it failed, I recommend it to other people often.

Comment: It would help to see this symbol relative to other text, to judge both the scale and relative positioning that is desired.

Comment: To the voters for closing: there are `\dotdiv` or `\dotminus` in the list of symbols, but they ***don't*** solve the problem. Closing as a duplicate of "how to look up" is meaningful only if the symbol is available without any special package that might change the appearance of all symbols.

Comment: @egreg: I'm inclined to disagree here, since there was no context given other than "I'm looking for a symbol like this" (despite the OP preferring a graphic/[`tikz`](http://ctan.org/pkg/pgf) solution). If the question is closed as a duplicate and this is not what the OP was after, I'm sure re-open votes would be cast.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is obsession!

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz,amsmath}
\newcommand{\Monus}{%
  \mathop{%
  \text{%
  \begin{tikzpicture}
  \fill (0,1ex) circle (0.75ex);
  \draw[thick] (-3ex,-.5ex) -- (3ex,-.5ex);
  \end{tikzpicture}%
}
}
}
\begin{document}
 $A \Monus B_{\Monus B}$
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 6):

Keeping this up for visibility since there doesn't seem to be any similar question on StackExchange.

Use `\dotdiv` from package `mathabx`.

Answer (score 5):

While `\dotdiv` from `mathabx` could be used (see [Importing a Single Symbol From a Different Font](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/14386/importing-a-single-symbol-from-a-different-font)), it would waste a math family.

Here's a way without any package other than `amsmath`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\providecommand{\dotdiv}{% Don't redefine it if available
  \mathbin{% We want a binary operation
    \vphantom{+}% The same height as a plus or minus
    \text{% Change size in sub/superscripts
      \mathsurround=0pt % To be on the safe side
      \ooalign{% Superimpose the two symbols
        \noalign{\kern-.35ex}% but the dot is raised a bit
        \hidewidth$\smash{\cdot}$\hidewidth\cr % Dot
        \noalign{\kern.35ex}% Backup for vertical alignment
        $-$\cr % Minus
      }%
    }%
  }%
}

\begin{document}
$a-b\dotdiv c_{\dotdiv}$
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: how does this differ from `\dotdiv` or `\dotminus` or unicode U+2238?  if it is really different, and a published reference can be cited, i will be happy to submit it for unicode consideration.

Comment: @barbarabeeton I don't think it differs from those symbols. It's just the usual problem that loading `mathabx` has the known side effects.

Comment: Thanks you helped me alot. You should add \protect before \ooalign if you dont want to get into trouble when using the new symbol inside a caption :)

Comment: @Florian Better yet, replace `\providecommand{\dotdiv}` with `\ProvideDocumentCommand{\dotdiv}{}` (don't forget the `{}`).